# bash: sudo: permission denied

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, vlc, raspbian

VLC is running. Got the PID from pgrep vlc.

I want now to pause it manually since I would like it to run "submerged" (right now from another tty but probably as a daemon)

I tried to simply do `sudo "pause" > /usr/bin/vlc/` having got the path by doing `sudo ls -l /proc/<PID>/exe`.

The answer is, even running the sudo command, that the permission is denied.

For my surprise, if I enter root mode `sudo bash` and just type the same command, the answer is not that the permission is denied, but rather that the "`text file is busy`". I'd like to guess what text file. I thought that command (in that case) inputted data to the command input manually (apart from writing to a text file)

Comment: `sudo "pause" > /usr/bin/vlc/` does not do what you think it does. It executes the command `pause` as root and *writes the output of the `pause` command* to the file `/usr/bin/vlc/` (which looks like a directory, in which case writing to it is not a good idea) *as the ‘normal user’*, since `sudo` applies to the command being run (`pause`) but not things like redirection (`>`). **Think about what it is you're trying to do before you overwrite an important file.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you want to do.

Write to /proc/*pid of the program*/fd/0. The fd subdirectory contains the descriptors of all the opened files and file descriptor 0 is the standard input (1 is stdout and 2 is stderr).

Example

Terminal 1:

```
[ciupicri@hermes ~]$ cat
Xxx
```

Terminal 2:

```
[ciupicri@hermes ~]$ pidof cat
7417
[ciupicri@hermes ~]$ echo xxx > /proc/7417/fd/0
```

Taken from another stack overflow answer